Migrating from WKPDF to Gotenberg
I'm trying to migrate from wkhtmlpdfto gotenberg for the pdf generation. The problem is that the pdf generated by gotenberg is not equal as the one generated with wkhtmlpdf. It's like the layout is being made diverse.
I've set the same page size, margins etc..
Maybe is the problem how the scale method works in gotenberg.
This is how i set the options in gotenberg:
 $chromiumRequest = Gotenberg::chromium('http://gotenberg.kanbanbox.com:3000')->pdf()->assets(...$this->getFontAssets())
            ->margins(
                0.0 . 'mm',
                0.0 . 'mm',
                1.0 . 'mm',
                1.0 . 'mm',
            );

        $chromiumRequest->scale($dimensionsTemplate->getZoom() ?? 0.5);

        if ($dimensionsTemplate->getPageOrientation()->equals(Orientation::LANDSCAPE)) {
            $chromiumRequest->landscape();
        }

        $paperFormat = $dimensionsTemplate->getPageFormat();

        if ($paperFormat === PaperFormat::HALF_LETTER) {
            $chromiumRequest->paperSize('140mm', '216mm');
        } elseif ($paperFormat === PaperFormat::CUSTOM) {
            $pageHeight = $dimensionsTemplate->getPageHeight();
            $pageWidth  = $dimensionsTemplate->getPageWidth();
            if ($pageHeight !== null && $pageHeight > 0 && $pageWidth !== null && $pageWidth > 0) {
                $chromiumRequest->paperSize($pageWidth . 'mm', $pageHeight . 'mm');
            }
        } else {
            $chromiumRequest->paperSize(PaperFormat::getDimensions($paperFormat)['width'] . 'mm', PaperFormat::getDimensions($paperFormat)['height'] . 'mm');
        }

this is wkpdf:
 $commandLine =
                $commandName
                . ' --orientation ' . $dimensionsTemplate->getPageOrientation()->value
                . ' --zoom ' . 0.78 * ($dimensionsTemplate->getZoom() ?? 1.0)
                . ' --margin-top ' . $dimensionsTemplate->getMarginTop()
                . ' --margin-right ' . $dimensionsTemplate->getMarginRight()
                . ' --margin-bottom ' . $dimensionsTemplate->getMarginBottom()
                . ' --margin-left ' . $dimensionsTemplate->getMarginLeft();

            $paperFormat = $dimensionsTemplate->getPageFormat();
            if ($paperFormat === PaperFormat::HALF_LETTER) {
                //half letter is the only format not supported by WkPdf, so we need to specify the width and height
                $commandLine .= ' --page-height 216 --page-width 140';
            } elseif ($paperFormat === PaperFormat::CUSTOM) {
                $pageHeight = $dimensionsTemplate->getPageHeight();
                $pageWidth  = $dimensionsTemplate->getPageWidth();
                if ($pageHeight !== null && $pageHeight > 0 && $pageWidth !== null && $pageWidth > 0) {
                    $commandLine .= ' --page-height ' . $pageHeight . ' --page-width ' . $pageWidth;
                }
            } else {
                $commandLine .= ' --page-size ' . $paperFormat->value;
            }

            $commandLine .= ' --disable-smart-shrinking'
                . $webArgument[$i]
                . ' ' . $tmpPdfChunkName[$i]
                . ' 2>&1'; // to write to STDOUT

This is the result of comparing the two generated pdf, green one is generated using wkhtmlpdf and the red one is generated using gotenberg (I used the same html files for both):


it does look like tweaking the zoom a bit would line everything up better; and the zoom calculations don't look consistent between samples

Thanks to everybody. My final solution was to scale the gotenberg template and keep a margin of difference.
